# Did I wire the outlet to my dryer wrong?

Tags: electrical, wiring

The way my house was built means that the electrical panel is at the opposite end of the house from the kitchen, living area, and laundry, so I have to run long cables to get electricity to where it's needed.

When I installed the dryer outlet (dryer draws 30 amps) I used 40 feet of 10/3 wire.

According to [this chart](https://thirdgens.com/2018/02/16/wire-gauge-chart-vs-amps-vs-length/) I think I may have been supposed to use 8/3 wire for the dryer outlet.

If I move the dryer 12 feet further away (total of 52 feet of wire) then will I need to replace my 10/3 with 6/3?

Comment: House wiring is usually good for about 100 feet.  Would need 8 gauge if it is aluminum wire, but for that distance and size there is no/little savings over copper wire.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Voltage drop severity strongly relates to voltage.

That is exactly the standard voltage drop chart that we see *everybody* misuse for home electrical.  It's actually for boats, but it was purloined by the 3rd gen F-body site where it is also semi-correct. Regardless these are 12 volt charts.

The ***severity*** of voltage drop **is proportional to the voltage**. Why? Suppose a very long run *(not yours*) has a 6 volt drop.

If your voltage is 12 volts, that's 50% voltage drop, which is extremely severe and will result in failure of the circuit.

If your voltage is 120 volts, 6 volts is 5% voltage drop - *not great, not terrible*.

If your voltage is 240 volts, then 6 volts is 2.5% voltage drop, which is widely viewed as acceptable.

Now you see why using a chart made for 12 volts will give an answer that exaggerates voltage drop by 20 times.

Why do people go for this wrong chart? Because they're looking for a chart.  People don't make charts like this for 240V power, because the horizontal axis of the chart would start at 100' and go to 400' and peter out.  It's easier stated as a rule of thumb - for 240V you start thinking about voltage drop above 150', and think about two past 300'. If you're going much farther than that, solve your problem a different way.   Consider a voltage drop calculator if you need the sharp-pencil numbers.

Comment: I understand that you're trying to explain proportions. Thank you for answering the main question by pointing out that voltage drop is of little concern at the distances involved in my question. The rule of thumb helps a lot. That said, I feel like we've strayed a bit from the original question. I understand that X/Z is smaller than X/Y if Z>Y. That's just math. It would happen with portions and percentages of anything. For my learning - Should I understand that the absolute value (not percentage) of voltage drop depends only on the length of the wire it's in?

Comment: @THill3 Absolute voltage drop is based on the resistance in ohms of the installed wire, and the resistance per unit distance of common wire types are published E.G. 10 AWG is 0.9989 ohm per 1000 foot, remembering that you are doing a round trip.   So it's just Ohm's Law V=IR at that point.

Answer (score 7):

Nope, nopeitty nope nope nope.

That's a chart for 12VDC vehicle wiring, not 240VAC house wiring as for a dryer.

3V of drop is a big deal on 12V, and barely noticeable on 240V.

Your actual voltage drop (on 10AWG copper) as a percentage for 30A (which is more than your dryer will draw - it probably uses 24-26A) is [less than 2%](https://www.calculator.net/voltage-drop-calculator.html?necmaterial=copper&necwiresize=2&necconduit=pvc&necpf=0.85&material=aluminum&wiresize=0.8152&resistance=1.2&resistanceunit=okm&voltage=240&phase=ac&noofconductor=1&distance=52&distanceunit=feet&amperes=30&x=Calculate&ctype=nec) which is utterly unconcerning, at 52 feet.

Comment: If it helps, I'm in the USA, so the 240v is a double pole breaker and 2 hot wires. You're saying that I have the wrong chart. Can you point me to a correct wire gauge guide?

Comment: "two hots" is expected, normal, and changes nothing. A two pole 240V 30A breaker is...a 30A breaker. Not a 60A breaker. The bulk of the power flows from hot to hot - a bit for the 120V loads such as the dryer motor and control panel  flows from one hot to neutral.

Comment: NEC Table 310.15(B)(16) and use a voltage drop calculator if looking at long runs. If 52 feet is one end of your house to the other, you have no long runs in your house. And stick to the 60°C column unless you are using conduit or otherwise know better. The 90°C column is only for derating. 10-14 gauge are limited in notes that some folks who throw up the table won't show, though they might put the asterisk there. 10=30A, 12=20A and 14-15A, for all practical purposes in house wiring.